# Set & GET PHP Session value using JavaScript in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am developing a plugin in which I get data from API, and then the user has an option to add this data to the cart and purchase the product. Everything works perfectly, except once we reload the page, the user cart value gets lost. How can I solve this?

I think one solution is, If we add the cart object to the session, it will be easy to use that session value to get the cart object. For this, I added the below function

**my_file.js**

```
function savecartObj(cartObj) {
        $.post(
         'cartObj.php',
             {
                 cartobj  : cartObj
             }, 
             function success(data) {
                console.log(data);
              }
        );
    }
```

and in my **cartObj.php**

```
<?php
/** Set up WordPress environment, just in case */
$path = preg_replace('/wp-content(?!.*wp-content).*/','',__DIR__);
require_once($path.'wp-load.php');

session_id() || session_start();

nocache_headers();

$_SESSION['ajjx'] = $_POST;

$value = '';
  if (array_key_exists('ajjx', $_SESSION)) {
       if (array_key_exists('cartobj', $_SESSION['ajjx']) {
           $value = $_SESSION['ajjx']['cartobj'];
       }
  }


Header('Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf8');
die(json_encode(array(
    'result' => $_SESSION['ajjx']['cart_obj'], 
)));
```

Now I can see that `$_SESSION['ajjx']['cart_obj']` is set and in `console.log(data);` I can see the session value.  How can i use this value from `$_SESSION['ajjx']['cartobj']` as cartobj in **my_file.js**

> What I need is will create one file named **get_session.php** and in
> that file, I will call the value of `$_SESSION['ajjx']['cart_obj']` .
> And then once my plugin is loaded I will call the value in
> **get_session.php**  & need to take the obj from the file and then add that value to add to cart function in the **my_file.js**. In that way, page reload doesn't
> affect my cart.

***Update***

For getting the value I write the following function in my **my_file.js**

```
function get_cartObj(){
    $.post(
     'get_cartObj.php',
          function success(data) {
             console.log(data);
          }
    );
}
```

and in **get_cartObj.php**

```
<?php
/** Set up WordPress environment, just in case */
$path = preg_replace('/wp-content(?!.*wp-content).*/','',__DIR__);
require_once($path.'wp-load.php');

session_id() || session_start();

nocache_headers();


Header('Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf8');
json_encode(array(
    'result' => $_SESSION['ajjx']['cart_obj'], // This in case you want to return something to the caller
));
```

but here **get_cartObj()** is not working as expected. No data coming in `console.log(data);`

Comment: PHP sessions don't work on a lot of WP hosts using cookies instead, and you should not be sending AJAX requests directly to PHP files in your theme/plugin, it's a security risk and introduces new problems e.g. your JS uses a relative URL so wether it works depends on the page you're on. Use the REST API or at least the old `admin-ajax.php` API,. Also avoid storing objects and structured data in PHP sessions and cookies.

Answer (score 2):

The same way you saved it. Actually you can add a parameter to (save)CartObj:

```
function cartObj(operation, cartObj) {
    $.post(
     'cartObj.php',
         {
             op       : operation,
             cartobj  : cartObj
         }, 
         function success(data) {
            console.log(data);
          }
    );
}
```

and in the PHP code (7.4+ required because of the ?? operator)

```
if ($_POST['operation'] === 'set') {
    $_SESSION['ajjx']['cartObj'] = $_POST['cartObj'] ?? [ ];
}
$value = $_SESSION['ajjx']['cartObj'] ?? [ ];

Header('Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf8');
die(json_encode(['result' => $value]));
```

Now calling the function with 'set' will save the Javascript cart into session, using 'get' will recover the cart.

## update

You can also do it like this:

- assuming that your page might receive a cart *or it might not*,
- and you will always run the same AJAX code regardless,

then the PHP code must *avoid removing the cart* if the `cartObj` parameter is empty (you will need a different call to remove the cart when you need to do this; or you may do it from PHP).

```
session_id()||session_start();
if ('set' === $_POST['operation'] && !empty($_POST['cartObj'])) {
    $_SESSION['ajjx']['cartObj'] = $_POST['cartObj'];
}
Header('Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf8');
die(json_encode(['result'=>$_SESSION['ajjx']['cartObj']??[]]));
```

This way, if you reload the page *but the POSTed cart is now empty (because it's a reload)*, the AJAX script will *not* update the session, and it will return the previous session value.

Comment: Thank you for the quick support. What I need is currently the cart value disappears if the page reloads so  I need to prevent that. For this, the first step is to save the value as a session and the second step is to take the session value [object] once the page is loaded and add that object to the cart. I got stuck in the second step. Could you please read my question again? I edited that.

Comment: @AbilashErikson not sure if I got it right, for I'm not totally sure about this page reload business. You repeat the POST? I assumed not.

Comment: Hi, still I am not able to get session values in my my_file.js. I added my code to get the value in my question. Could you please check that?

Answer (score 0):

Before im going to answer the question i have some dubt to clear, it looks like you are in a wordpress environment but you are not using his AJAX standard procedures. Check it out here https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

About the issue since JS is client side and PHP is server side you need something to have the values available in JS. I can think of two option:

1. Print into the page with some PHP a little script tag which is made like this:

```php
<script>
var myObjectVar = '<?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['ajjx']['cart_obj']); ?>';
</script>
```

2. You make a new AJAX call as soon as the page load to read that same value from PHP again and then use it to make what you need to do